# Method calling in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm somewhat of a n00b to Python and I'm working on a tiny project. This is my code in src/sock.py

```
import socket
import config
class Server(socket.socket):
    def __init__(self):
        socket.socket.__init__(self, socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    def start(self):
        self.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.bind((config.bind_host, config.bind_port))
        self.listen(5)

        while True:
            pass
```

and my code in start.py

```
import src

Socket = src.sock

Socket.Server()
Socket.Server.start
```

but the Server doesn't seem to be starting. :(

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
Socket.Server()
```

will create a server instance. But since you don't assign that created instance to a variable, you can't use it or reach it (and it will be garbage collected very quickly).

```
Socket.Server.start
```

accesses the start method on the Server class (not the created instance, but the class). But again, you don't do anything with it. You don't call it, you don't assign it to anything. So it is in effect a noop.

You need to assign the created server instance to a variable, and then call the start method on that instance. Like so:

```
server = Socket.Server()
server.start()
```